# Table with fixed columns, horizontal scroll for other cols and global vertical scroll

Tags: html, css

Title is self explanotory. I tried different approaches ([one](https://codepen.io/barmaxon/pen/wvQzNaz), [two](https://codepen.io/barmaxon/pen/JjeRxPe)) but couldn't figure it out so far. With my tries, it seems like flexible part of my table doesn't want to be stretched inside global vertically scrollable space.
One of the examples:

**html**

```
<div class="staff outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <table class="fixed">
      <tr>
        <th>Header A</th>
        <th>Header A</th>
      </tr>
      <!-- ... -->
    </table>
    <table class="flexible">
      <tr>
        <td>col 1 - A</td>
        <td>col 2 - A (WITH LONGER CONTENT)</td>
        <td>col 3 - A</td>
        <td>col 4 - A</td>
        <td>col 5 - A</td>
      </tr>
      <!-- ... -->
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**scss**

```
.cell {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.global-table {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 300px;

  .table {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    .row {
      display: flex;
      .cell {
        max-width: 100px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
    }
  }

  .fixed {
    width: 200px;
  }

  .flexible {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;

    .cell {
      min-width: 50px;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Solved](https://codepen.io/barmaxon/pen/ZEmLYop) it by wrapping my flexible table and playing with height\width;

html

```
<div class="global-table">
  <div class="table fixed">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Header 1</div>
      <div class="cell">Sub header 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Header 2</div>
      <div class="cell">Sub header 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Header 3</div>
      <div class="cell">Sub header 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Header 4</div>
      <div class="cell">Sub header 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Header 5</div>
      <div class="cell">Sub header 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Header 6</div>
      <div class="cell">Sub header 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Header 7</div>
      <div class="cell">Sub header 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Header 8</div>
      <div class="cell">Sub header 8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Header 9</div>
      <div class="cell">Sub header 9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Header 10</div>
      <div class="cell">Sub header 10</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table flexible">
    <div class="cells">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">01</div>
        <div class="cell">02</div>
        <div class="cell">03</div>
        <div class="cell">04</div>
        <div class="cell">05</div>
        <div class="cell">06</div>
        <div class="cell">07</div>
        <div class="cell">08</div>
        <div class="cell">09</div>
        <div class="cell">10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">01</div>
        <div class="cell">02</div>
        <div class="cell">03</div>
        <div class="cell">04</div>
        <div class="cell">05</div>
        <div class="cell">06</div>
        <div class="cell">07</div>
        <div class="cell">08</div>
        <div class="cell">09</div>
        <div class="cell">10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">01</div>
        <div class="cell">02</div>
        <div class="cell">03</div>
        <div class="cell">04</div>
        <div class="cell">05</div>
        <div class="cell">06</div>
        <div class="cell">07</div>
        <div class="cell">08</div>
        <div class="cell">09</div>
        <div class="cell">10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">01</div>
        <div class="cell">02</div>
        <div class="cell">03</div>
        <div class="cell">04</div>
        <div class="cell">05</div>
        <div class="cell">06</div>
        <div class="cell">07</div>
        <div class="cell">08</div>
        <div class="cell">09</div>
        <div class="cell">10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">01</div>
        <div class="cell">02</div>
        <div class="cell">03</div>
        <div class="cell">04</div>
        <div class="cell">05</div>
        <div class="cell">06</div>
        <div class="cell">07</div>
        <div class="cell">08</div>
        <div class="cell">09</div>
        <div class="cell">10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">01</div>
        <div class="cell">02</div>
        <div class="cell">03</div>
        <div class="cell">04</div>
        <div class="cell">05</div>
        <div class="cell">06</div>
        <div class="cell">07</div>
        <div class="cell">08</div>
        <div class="cell">09</div>
        <div class="cell">10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">01</div>
        <div class="cell">02</div>
        <div class="cell">03</div>
        <div class="cell">04</div>
        <div class="cell">05</div>
        <div class="cell">06</div>
        <div class="cell">07</div>
        <div class="cell">08</div>
        <div class="cell">09</div>
        <div class="cell">10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">01</div>
        <div class="cell">02</div>
        <div class="cell">03</div>
        <div class="cell">04</div>
        <div class="cell">05</div>
        <div class="cell">06</div>
        <div class="cell">07</div>
        <div class="cell">08</div>
        <div class="cell">09</div>
        <div class="cell">10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">01</div>
        <div class="cell">02</div>
        <div class="cell">03</div>
        <div class="cell">04</div>
        <div class="cell">05</div>
        <div class="cell">06</div>
        <div class="cell">07</div>
        <div class="cell">08</div>
        <div class="cell">09</div>
        <div class="cell">10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">01</div>
        <div class="cell">02</div>
        <div class="cell">03</div>
        <div class="cell">04</div>
        <div class="cell">05</div>
        <div class="cell">06</div>
        <div class="cell">07</div>
        <div class="cell">08</div>
        <div class="cell">09</div>
        <div class="cell">10</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

scss

```
.cell {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.global-table {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 300px;

  .table {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    .row {
      display: flex;
      .cell {
        max-width: 100px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
    }
  }

  .fixed {
    width: 200px;
  }

  .flexible {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    .cells {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      overflow-y: hidden;

      .cell {
        min-width: 50px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```